# I can't get passed Selenium ElementNotInteractableException: button could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

There are 3 buttons, each button is labeled the same thing on a website. How can I click the 2nd button in python?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary checkout-step-action-done layout-quarter">
```

So far I have only tried this since I'm a newbie in selenium but it only clicks 1st button.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".layout-quarter").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary checkout-step-action-done layout-quarter']").click()
```

https://pastebin.com/A9VwTYdi

I am pasting HTML on pastebin because it is quite long. I recommend using ctrl-f, to find the 3 buttons. The button I want to click says "Continue to payment" on it.

Answer (score 1):

okay, I've solved the problem. I was able to shorten the code by using this.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".layout-quarter")[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to work for me but I'm sure there is a better solution.

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".layout-quarter")
for value in button:
    if value.text == 'CONTINUE TO PAYMENT':
        value.click()
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[value='CONTINUE TO PAYMENT']'").click()